# movimento do bispo no xadrez

Tags: c

Montei esse código porém como sabemos o bispo se movimenta nas diagonais, mas no meu código ele está se movimentando reto... o "x" representa as casas que o bispo pode passar. Sabem me dizer como faço para colocar as casa nas diagonais?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int linha, coluna, l, c;

printf("Movimento de um bispo no xadrez\n");;
printf("Digite a linha que o bispo se encontra: ");
scanf("%d", &linha);
printf("Digite a coluna que o bispo se encontra: ");
scanf("%d", &coluna);

printf("\nMovimentos possiveis:\n\n");
printf("      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  \n");
printf("   -------------------------\n");

l = 1;
while(l <= 8){
    printf("%3d |", l);
    l++;
    
    c = 1;
    while(c <= 8){
        if(l == linha && c == coluna){
            printf(" o ");
        }
        if(l == linha || c == coluna){
            printf(" x ");
        }
        else{
            printf(" - ");
        }
        c++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: O mais intuitivo é partir da posição onde o bispo está e navegar em cada direção com um `for`. Isso é feito apenas modificando os incrementos em x e y ou l e c se quiser. No caso seria +1 +1, +1 -1, -1 +1, -1 -1, para cada direção respetivamente.

Comment: Mas como eu iria implementar isso no código, tentei aqui e não consegui

Answer (score 1):

Para você conseguir mover o bispo na diagonal, seria ideal você utilizar uma matriz para você visualizar o movimento no tabuleiro, sabendo a linha e a coluna e também para você armazenar a casa onde o bispo está

```
       1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8  
   -----------------------------------------
  1 | 1,1  1,2  1,3  1,4  1,5  1,6  1,7  1,8 
  2 | 2,1  2,2  2,3  2,4  2,5  2,6  2,7  2,8 
  3 | 3,1  3,2  3,3  3,4  3,5  3,6  3,7  3,8 
  4 | 4,1  4,2  4,3  4,4  4,5  4,6  4,7  4,8 
  5 | 5,1  5,2  5,3  5,4  5,5  5,6  5,7  5,8 
  6 | 6,1  6,2  6,3  6,4  6,5  6,6  6,7  6,8 
  7 | 7,1  7,2  7,3  7,4  7,5  7,6  7,7  7,8 
  8 | 8,1  8,2  8,3  8,4  8,5  8,6  8,7  8,8
```

utilizando a matriz como mapa, você consegue conseguirá ver que existem padrões baseado na coluna e linha que escolher, que seriam:

para a **diagonal superior esquerda** do número que você escolheu, sempre será:

```
linha-1 e coluna-1
```

para a **diagonal superior direita**:

```
linha-1 e coluna+1
```

**diagonal inferior esquerda**:

```
linha+1 e coluna-1
```

**diagonal inferior direita**:

```
linha+1 e coluna+1
```

Código de cada for:

```
    // usando 2 para definir casa disponível, 7 para posição atual e 0 para casa não possível de ir
   // separando cada for, para que fique mais fácil o entendimento do código.

// -------      DIAGONAL ESQUERDA CIMA    ---------
           for(i=linha;i>0;i--){
            for(j=coluna;j>0;j--){
                if(i == flagx - 1 && j == flagy - 1){
                    flagx=i; flagy=j;
                    tabuleiro[i][j]=2;
                }
          }
        }
// -------      DIAGONAL DIREITA BAIXO    ---------
          for(i=linha;i<=8;i++){
            for(j=coluna;j<=8;j++){
                if(i == flagx + 1 && j == flagy + 1){
                    flagx=i; flagy=j;
                    tabuleiro[i][j]=2;
                }
          }
    }
// -------      DIAGONAL DIREITA CIMA    ---------
        for(i=8;i>0;i--){
            for(j=8;j>0;j--){
                if(i == flagx - 1 && j == flagy + 1){
                    flagx = i;
                    flagy = j;
                    tabuleiro[i][j]=2;
                }
            }
        }
// -------      DIAGONAL ESQUERDA BAIXO    ---------
        for(i=0;i<=8;i++){
            for(j=0;j<=8;j++){

                if(i == flagx + 1 && j == flagy - 1){
                    flagx = i;
                    flagy = j;
                    tabuleiro[i][j]=2;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/HBAo7XtB6 código completo para você testar caso queira

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

Outro colega entretanto já respondeu quando já estava aqui a colocar a resposta. De qualquer forma respondo na mesma que fica com duas formas de aplicar a mesma lógica que eu mencionei.

Meu exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_CASAS 8

void gera_movimentos_bispo(int casas_bispo[MAX_CASAS][MAX_CASAS], int linha_bispo, int coluna_bispo) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = linha_bispo + 1, j = coluna_bispo + 1; i < MAX_CASAS && j < MAX_CASAS; i++, j++) {
        casas_bispo[i][j] = 1;
    }
    for (i = linha_bispo - 1, j = coluna_bispo - 1; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--) {
        casas_bispo[i][j] = 1;
    }
    for (i = linha_bispo - 1, j = coluna_bispo + 1; i >= 0 && j < MAX_CASAS; i--, j++) {
        casas_bispo[i][j] = 1;
    }
    for (i = linha_bispo + 1, j = coluna_bispo - 1; i < MAX_CASAS && j >= 0; i++, j--) {
        casas_bispo[i][j] = 1;
    }
}

void mostra_movimentos_bispo(int casas_bispo[MAX_CASAS][MAX_CASAS], int linha_bispo, int coluna_bispo) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CASAS; i++) {
        printf("%3d |", i + 1);
        for (j = 0; j < MAX_CASAS; j++) {
            if(i == linha_bispo && j == coluna_bispo) {
                printf(" o ");
            } else {
                printf(" %c ", casas_bispo[i][j] == 1 ? 'x' : '-');
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int linha, coluna;

    printf("Movimento de um bispo no xadrez\n");;
    printf("Digite a linha que o bispo se encontra: ");
    scanf("%d", &linha);
    printf("Digite a coluna que o bispo se encontra: ");
    scanf("%d", &coluna);

    printf("\nMovimentos possiveis:\n\n");
    printf("      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  \n");
    printf("   -------------------------\n");

    int casas_bispo[MAX_CASAS][MAX_CASAS];
    memset(casas_bispo, 0, sizeof(casas_bispo)); //inicializa a zeros
    linha--; //ajusta para array que começa em 0
    coluna--; //ajusta para array que começa em 0

    gera_movimentos_bispo(casas_bispo, linha, coluna);
    mostra_movimentos_bispo(casas_bispo, linha, coluna);
    return 0;
}
```

Se executar com linha 4 e coluna 4 dá lhe o seguinte:

```
Movimentos possiveis:

      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
   -------------------------
  1 | x  -  -  -  -  -  x  - 
  2 | -  x  -  -  -  x  -  - 
  3 | -  -  x  -  x  -  -  - 
  4 | -  -  -  o  -  -  -  - 
  5 | -  -  x  -  x  -  -  - 
  6 | -  x  -  -  -  x  -  - 
  7 | x  -  -  -  -  -  x  - 
  8 | -  -  -  -  -  -  -  x
```

A função `gera_movimentos_bispo` tem a tal lógica que eu mencionei em comentário para partir do local onde o bispo está e gerar os movimentos.

Utilizei também um tabuleiro adicional para marcar as casas onde o bispo pode ir, com o valor 1, na otica de simplificar.

[Pode ver também o resultado no Ideone se preferir](https://ideone.com/Wka7wB)

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado :)